# Default resample method used by GEE when exporting images?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to know what the default resample method will be used when I export image like this :

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image,
  description: 'imagetest',
  **scale: 1000,**
  region:aoi,
  folder: test', 
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels: 9999999999999
});
```

Nearest？ mean？ cubic?...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample), nearest neighbor is the default resampling method. Also see Tyler Erickson's discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262266/67264) for more.